# Can I use the pyschocats' tutorial to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 with a minimal install disc?

Tags: 12.04, installation, upgrade, ubuntu-minimal, alternate

[Psychocats](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/minimal) describes a minimal install cd.   Can I use this to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably NOT, because the minimal install CD actually is a "net install" which fetches everything over the internet, and I don't think it has the upgrade "logic" built into the regular CDs.

I think you're much better off doing a `do-release-upgrade` from within 11.10 itself...

Comment: for a clean install, you don't **need** the network connection to just install a minimal system, though, do you?

Comment: Oh you absolutely do for the Ubuntu minimal CD, *unlike* the Debian minimal CD, say. The Ubuntu minimal CD is ~20-25 MB -- all it contains is a kernel image and network drivers...  Psychocats says *Note: a high-speed wired internet connection is recommended for a minimal installation. *